# Constructing a workflow to create a new list object when editing a different list object

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

im busy investigating how to do this, and if anybody has some guidance that would be great. :)

I have 3 lists.

- Candidates
- Positions
- Applications

An Application object consists of a Candidate and a Position.

Currently, I am creating a Position, creating a Candidate, and then creating and Application using both.

Is it possible to, at the Candidate level, select a position from a Position Lookup field and then on save, automatically create an Application object? Using the Candidate object, and whatever positions is selected (multi-select)

First time using Sharepoint and Sharepoint Designer, so I'm playing around a bit with the workflow editor but now sure Im getting it right...

If anybody has some workflow experience and might have some pointers for me, I would appreciate it. :)

thanks!

---

**Update**: Here is my workflow so far for the 'Candidate' list, and is kicked off when an item is created.

So here I cam creating a new item in 'Job Applications' (I dont understand yet what the 'Output to Variable' field means, and have left it untouched)
[image: So here I cam creating a new item in 'Job Applications' (I dont understand yet what the 'Output to Variable' field means, and have left it untouched)]

For the 'Applicant' field, I am assigning it 'CurrentItem:ID', which I assume is the ID required for the Candidate object lookup field which that 'Applicant' field has.
[image: For the 'Applicant' field, I am assigning it 'CurrentItem:ID', which I assume is the ID required for the Candidate object lookup field which that 'Applicant' field has.]

For the 'Position' field, I am assigning it 'CurrentItem:Applications'. This field under Candidates is an 'Positions' object multi-select lookup field. (So we can select multiple positions the applicant is applying for from the 'Position' object list.)
[image: For the 'Position' field, I am assigning it 'CurrentItem:Applications'. This field under Candidates is an 'Positions' object multi-select lookup field. (So we can select multiple positions the applicant is applying for from the 'Position' object list.)]

So with all that done and said, no new Applications object is created when a new Candidate object is created with those fields supplied.

Am I doing something wrong still?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. In the workflow, whenever you create the Candidate list item, you can kick off a workflow that uses the Candidate info, and the Position field in the Candidate list to then create an Application list item. Your logic should look similar to this:

```
Create item in "Applications" (list) 
Field: Candidate = Value:CurrentItem:Candidate
Field: Position = Value:CurrentItem:Position
(any other fields you want to capture)
```

This is the screen you should see (nevermind the sample data):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike! I tried following your suggestion, but still couldnt get it working correctly.
I've updated my question with a snapshot of my workflow creation. Hopefully it might highlight where Im going wrong... thanks again!

Comment: If you are running this script as a system account, the workflow will not execute. Also, remove the "Application Status" field and try again. It may be hung up there.